# How to fix 'PHP cgi error' in PhpStorm under Mac OS X?

Tags: php, macos, phpstorm, cgi

I get php-cgi not found error by PhpStorm (and 502 bad gateway page in browser) when I try to run my script.

`php -v` says `PHP 7.3.9 (cli) (built: Nov  9 2019 08:08:13) ( NTS )`
php.ini was created by myself and was located in /etc folder.

Here is screenshot of PhpStorm settings:
[image]

I tried to reinstall php via homebrew with --with-cgi flag but I get error `Error: invalid option: --with-cgi`

What to do in this case?

Comment: The error suggests that you are trying to use PhpStorm's built-in simple web server (which is limited anyway). Can you use proper Apache/nginx/etc instead? It will be much better.

Comment: To elaborate on the above: to preview PHP pages in web browser via PhpStorm you need to create at least one deployment configuration. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-synchronization-with-a-remote-host.html#server-access-config